# Creating a greater than but less than function in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to write a a code that pulls information from a list in SharePoint that ranges in numbers associated with one term.  For instance:

```
1-3 = Low
4-6 = Moderate
7-9 = High
10 = Critical
```

I have the following code but I can't seem to get it to work right.  What I want to do is it to only pull from these ranges above:

```
<xsl:variable name="RM1A" select="count($Rows[@Impact $gt;='01' -and- $lt;='03][@Likelihood $gt;='01' -and- $lt;='02'])"/>
```

The problem is that it works but pulls all numbers that are greater than 01 and doesn't stop at 03.  I am completely new at XML coding so be gentle.

I am looking for an easier way maybe or the right syntax for doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, escaped `<` and `>` are, in order, `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Then, expression like `and &lt;='03'` is not valid. It is considered missing left operand of `<=`. And the last point will be only a suggestion; you might want convert the attributes to number, to safely compare its value as number. So, the following is one possible valid expression (wrapped for readability) :

```
count(
    $Rows[number(@Impact) &gt;=1 and number(@Impact) &lt;=3]
         [number(@Likelihood) &gt;=1 and number(@Likelihood) &lt;=2]
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I was not sure about how to get it to work since I have never really messed with XML before.  it makes sense that it would need the second @Impact.  I have searched all over the internet for this and couldn't find anything so thank you so much for your help!